# sed substitution over a range

Tags: bash, sed

I have file with the following entries:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz1
234
567
890
```

What would the sed expression to remove the trailing newline characters from it for the first 10 lines ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say

```
sed '1,9 { H; d; }; 10 { x; G; s/\n//g; }' filename
```

What this does is:

```
1,9 {            # For the first nine lines:
  H              # append line to hold buffer
  d              # then discard it.
}
10 {             # in the tenth line:
  x              # swap the assembled lines in the hold buffer with the pattern
                 # space containing the tenth line
  G              # append hold buffer (holding the tenth line) to the pattern
                 # space (holding the previous nine lines)
  s/\n//g        # remove all newlines from that.
}
```

Alternatively,

```
sed '1 { N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N; s/\n//g; }' filename
```

will also work. When processing the first line, it fetches the next nine (using nine `N` commands), then removes the newlines between them. However, I find this less easibly adaptable and therefore less pretty.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be done without `sed`.

```
head file -n 10 | tr -d '\n'; tail file -n +11
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
# With GNU sed, you need `sed -u`.
{ sed 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\n//g;q'; cat -; } <file
```

or:

```
awk 'FNR < 10 {printf "%s", $0; next};1' file
```

Comment: Don't use input redirection (`awk 'script' < file`) with awk unless you have a specific goal in mind as it removes awks ability to set (and so your ability to use) the `FILENAME` variable and you cant process multiple files that way and it has other negative impacts for some other requirements. Just let awk open the file itself: `awk 'script' file`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Fair point. But `<file` save you from many cases, like permission, file start with `-`.

Comment: You can't use it in general (for multiple files) so don't use it in particular (for a single file). Also the unlikely things it saves you from aren't worth giving up the likely things you will need that doing so stops you from using. It's not like awk can't handle those things (awk will handle a file name starting with `-` just fine btw), it's just different from how shell handles them.

Comment: @EdMorton: No, GNU tools often have extensions to handle options after command, so I want to guard from that case. But it seems that gawk doesn't have this issue

Answer (score 1):

Using perl, chomp removes newlines.

```
perl -pe 'chomp if $. < 10' file

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234
567
890
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '11,$b;1h;1!H;10!d;g;s/\n//g' file
```

From line 11 to the end of the file (could also be writtern `1,10!b`) bail out and print as normal. Store the first line as is in the hold space. Append lines 2 to 10 in the hold space. Delete lines 1 to 9. Replace line 10 by the hold space, delete all newlines and print.

Answer (score -1):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR<10?OFS:RS)}1' file
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz1 234
567
890

$ awk '{ORS=(NR<5?OFS:RS)}1' file
abc def ghi jkl mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz1
234
567
890

$ awk '{ORS=(NR>3 && NR<7 ? OFS : RS)}1' file
abc
def
ghi
jkl mno pqr stu
vwx
yz1
234
567
890
```

Comment: Didn't downvote but i'd guess maybe because you are replacing the newline with space instead of removing ?

Comment: An easy fix obviously (replace `OFS` with `""`) but since there's no expected output in the question we're just guessing what the OP wants. In my experience when people want to remove the newlines they actually want to replace them with a blank char but YMMV.

Comment: I know, that was the only reason i could think of though... Dunno maybe you upset someone.

Comment: I suspect it might be someone who thinks that when asked how to use a screwdriver to drive a nail into the wall it'd be inappropriate to suggest using a hammer instead.